# Действия в чате. не могу понять в чем ошибка

Tags: php, чат, javascript

Делаю чат на php/js. Никак не могу сделать вывод действий в чате. 
Код js функции:

```
function to_do() {
    var mes = document.getElementById("send_mes").value;
    var action = document.getElementById("act");
    var a = action.options[action.selectedIndex].value;
    var log1 = document.getElementById("log").value;
    var room1 = document.getElementById("room");
    var r1 = room1.options[room1.selectedIndex].value;
    if (a == "hi") {
        mes = log1 + " приветствует всех. " + mes;
    }
    if (a == "bye") {
        mes = "***" + log1 + " прощается. " + mes + "***";
    }
    if (a == "my") {
        mes = "***" + log1 + " " + mes + "***";
    }
    alert(mes);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mes.php",
        data: "do=" + mes + "&room=" + r1,
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

php обработчик:

```
function Load($r) {
    $user1 = $_SESSION['name'].
    ":";
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $last_message_id = intval($_POST['last']).
    "";
    $data = time();
    $active = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_active = '$data' WHERE name = '$name'");
    $str = "SELECT * FROM mess WHERE (id > $last_message_id) AND (log1 = '$user1' OR log2 = '' OR (log2 = '$user1' AND hid = '1') OR (log2 >'' AND hid ='0') OR (actt = '1')) AND (room = '$r') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30";

    $query = mysql_query($str);

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

        $js = 'var chat = $("#mes");';

        $messages = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $messages[] = $row;
        }
        $last_message_id = $messages[0]['id'];

        $messages = array_reverse($messages);

        foreach($messages as $value) {

            $rt = substr($value['log1'], 0, -1);
            $lp = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = '$rt'");
            $pl = mysql_result($lp, 0);
            $lo = mysql_query("SELECT color FROM user WHERE id = '$pl'");
            $ul = mysql_result($lo, 0);
            if ($value['actt'] == "1") {

                $js. = 'chat.append("<span style=\"display:block; margin:4px 0;\"><span style = \"cursor:pointer; \">be be be</span>  <span ></span></span>");';
            } else if ($value['log2'] == $value['log1'] && $value['log2'] < > "" && $value["log2"] < > NULL) {

                $js. = 'chat.append("<span style=\"display:block; margin:4px 0;\"><span style = \"cursor:pointer; \" onclick=\"komu('.$pl.
                ');\">'.$value['log1'].
                '</span><span style=\"color:'.$ul.
                '\"> '.$value['mess'].
                '</span></span>");';

            } else if ($value['log2'] == $user1 && $value['hid'] == "1") {
                $js. = 'chat.append("<span style=\"border:dashed 1px white; background-color:gray; display:block;padding: 4px;color:white;margin:4px 0;\">Приватное сообщение от <span style = \"cursor:pointer;color:'.$ul.
                '; \" onclick=komu('.$pl.
                ');>'.$value['log1'].
                '</span><br/><span style=\"color:'.$ul.
                '\">'.$value['mess'].
                '</span></span>");';

            } else if ($value['log1'] == $user1 && $value['hid'] == "1") {
                $js. = 'chat.append("<span style=\"border:dashed 1px white; background-color:gray; display:block;padding: 4px;color:white;margin:4px 0;\">Приватное сообщение для <span style = \"cursor:pointer; color:'.$ul.
                '; \" onclick=komu('.$pl.
                ');>'.$value['log1'].
                '</span><br/><span style=\"color:'.$ul.
                '\">'.$value['mess'].
                '</span></span>");';

            } else {

                $js. = 'chat.append("<span style=\"display:block; margin:4px 0;\"><span style = \"cursor:pointer; \" onclick=\"komu('.$pl.
                ');\">'.$value['log1'].
                '</span>  <span style=\"color:'.$ul.
                '\">'.$value['log2'].
                ''.$value['mess'].
                '</span></span>");';

            }
        }

        $js. = "last_message_id = $last_message_id;";

        echo $js;
    }
}
```

Суть в том, что в базу всё записывается. И сообщения выводит. Для действия только то, что между `if($value['actt'] == "1")`

**Обновление**

Чуть не забыл. Функция вывода сообщений и действий в чат.

```
function Load(rom) {
    if (!load_in_process) {
        load_in_process = true; // загрузка началась
        // отсылаем запрос серверу, который вернёт нам javascript
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mes.php",
            dataType: "script",
            data: "act=" + rom + "&last=" + last_message_id + "&rand=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
            success: function(res) {

                load_in_process = false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Несколько советов.

1. Если вы начали использовать JQuery используйте его полноценно.
2. Забудьте if else if else if... Для этого есть очень удобная конструкция switch - case!

Comment: так лучше не делать, чем вам json не угодил ? зачем вы возвращаете все время скрипт ? зачем используя jquery вы пишите document.getElementById ?

Comment: eicto, Я использую append что бы новые сообщения в чате появлялись снизу. через json немного неудобно возвращать js

Comment: Palmervan, 1) jquery только начал изучать, пока знаю его не полноценно. 2) Там немного не получается сделать Switch - case. может мозги не доходят, но суть то не в этом.

Comment: @Габит Серикбаев там даже switch case не надо объект маппинга вполне хватит:

     var map={ hi: "приветсвует", bye: "прощается" }